# Is LAMP messing up with my PHP?

Tags: php, slider, wamp, lamp

I'm trying to fix a website, with a slider in front page. When I see it in local, there is no problem whatsoever. Once online, though ...
Local slider:
[image: local slider]
Online slider:
[image: online slider]

The only difference I see between these is that the local passes thorugh WAMP and the online through LAMP. Any idea ?

Comment: It seems your folder structure is not identical on your remote server

Comment: Use the browser debugger on the live site page to see what and why the imsages have not loaded

Comment: @Shaeldon I basically copied my local www on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be caused by 2 main reasons:

1. Case sensitivity. Linux is case sensitivity to it's files. while Windows is not. so if you have defined path like `folder/image.png` when the real name is actully `Folder/image.png`. it will only work in windows.
   make sure you defined in your files the exact path.
2. Directory structure is not similar.

Comment: Now that you provided a error analysis where is the solution/answer?

Comment: @Rizler123, as I said before the solution is to make sure you defined in your file the exact path (with uppercase/lowercase letters). which is proably what went wrong. I had similar issues before.

Comment: Right now you are just guessing that this is the problem, but you don't have a specific solution which solves OP's problem

Comment: @Rizer123 That's an educated guess which from my experience is probably the solution to his problem. just wait for his response

Comment: @Rizler123 Dan is right, if my problem is that the problem comes from the case sensitiveness, the solution doesn't need to be mentionned.

Comment: Thank you sir. Apparently, windows like putting PNG instead of png.